# Create a list of dicts by selectively picking up values from adjacent columns as the dict key-value pair and iterate through the df's columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with a set of triage columns, 1_A, 1_B, 1_C, 2_A, 2_b, 2_C..eg below.
I am looking to create a list of dictionarie, where a dict pair is formed/extracted only when _C column row has value (which forms the dict key) between 30 and 90, and the corresponding dict value is _B column's value.

```
Index  1_A  1_B  1_C   2_A  2_B  2_C  3_A  3_B  3_C  Class  timestamp              Cost
67     100  3.3  85.5            175            267   B     01-01-2021 00:00:00     1000
68     100  3.3  85              175            267   B     01-01-2021 00:00:00     1000
79     100  3.3  20        2.8   89            100    B     01-01-2021 00:00:00     1000
84     100  3.3  20              175       3     80   B     01-01-2021 00:00:00     100
85     100  3.3  20              175       3.1   70   B     01-01-2021 00:00:00     1000
86     100  3.3  19             175        4     60   B     01-01-2021 00:00:00     1000
99     100  3.3  19             175             267   B     01-01-2021 00:00:00     1000
```

So, for eg: the list of dicts from the above eg df would be
`[{85.5 : 3.3}, {85 : 3.3}, {89 : 2.8}, {80 : 3}, {70 : 3.1}, {60: 4}]`.

Can you advise how i can best tackle this ?

I guess the logic would form by traversing every _C columns and if condition mathches, fetch the value from 1 column behind (_B column), and update the list.; and continue traversing all _C, _B columns in that fashion ?

Comment: Your data with empty strings make it hard to copy/paste. Here's an approach: `stack/melt` the `_A,_B,_C` columns, `query` for valid `_C` values, `set_index` the `_C` column, then `to_dict()`.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample/dummy python/pandas statements ?

Comment: @QuangHoang <adding the tagname> :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if '_C' in col]
values = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x[(x>=30) & (x<=90)].
                                to_frame().
                                join(df[f"{x.name.split('_')[0]}_B"]).
                                set_index(x.name).to_dict()[f"{x.name.split('_')[0]}_B"]).values
values = {k: v for d in values for k, v in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{85.5: 3.3, 85.0: 3.3, 89: 2.8, 80: 3.0, 70: 3.1, 60: 4.0}
```