# How to create a dictionary from two dataframes mapping col1 of 1st df to col1 of 2nd df, and do this for all columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

df1

```
1_A   2_A  3_A
3.3   nan   nan
3.3   nan   nan
nan   4.3   nan
nan   nan   3.2
nan   nan   3.5
```

df2

```
1_B   2_B  3_B
83   nan   nan
87   nan   nan
nan   64   nan
nan   nan   66
nan   nan   68
```

**Desired list of dicts :**

```
[{83 : 3.3 },{87 :3.3 },{64 :4.3 },{66 :3.2 },{68: 3.5}]
```

Comment: Why are you asking what appears to be the same question as [your previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69543109/create-a-list-of-dicts-by-selectively-picking-up-values-from-adjacent-columns-as)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a list of dicts by selectively picking up values from adjacent columns as the dict key-value pair and iterate through the df's columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69543109/create-a-list-of-dicts-by-selectively-picking-up-values-from-adjacent-columns-as)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `stack`

```
d = dict(zip(df2.stack(),df1.stack()))
d
Out[58]: {83.0: 3.3, 87.0: 3.3, 64.0: 4.3, 66.0: 3.2, 68.0: 3.5}
```

Comment: stack does not retain the nan's, can i retain the nans so the dimensions are same

Comment: @asimo do with stack(skipena= False) then you need to remove all nan in both